# Remove First & Last Items from a List of string

Tags: c#, linq

Have a `Dictionary <string,string>` as follows.

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "d.b.f", "x1" },
                { "d.z.x.f", "x2" },
                { "d.y.f.x.f", "x3" }
            };
```

Want to construct a new Dictionary with first (d) & last (f) excluded from each key in dictionary. So result looks

```
var res = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "b", "x1" },
                { "z.x", "x2" },
                { "y.f.x", "x3" }
            };
```

I tried as follows.

```
var abc = d.Select(x => Helper(x));

        private static KeyValuePair<string,string> Helper(KeyValuePair<string,string> x)
        {
            var array =  x.Key.Split('.').ToList();
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(string.Join(".", array.Where(z => array.IndexOf(z) != 0 && array.IndexOf(z) != array.Count - 1)), x.Value);
        }
```

now abc has my required result. Is there an efficient way to do the same thing?

Comment: Solution depends on: how large your dictionary, how large your keys, how frequent you need to do this compared to search in this dictionary. Most complex of solutions is to build trie out of your keys, or suffix tree (in suffix tree case you don't need to trim keys, you just search from different suffix).

Comment: Also, are you sure that your current method gives you the correct results? Unless I'm missing something, given `d` the last key in `abc` should be `"y.f.x.f"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you will always have `d.` in front, and `.f` on the end, you could simply do a substring of your key.

```
        private static KeyValuePair<string, string> Helper(KeyValuePair<string, string> x)
        {
            // starting index of 2, to skip "d.", and length of the key minus "d." and ".f"
            var substring = x.Key.Substring(2, x.Key.Length - 4);
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(substring, x.Value);
        }
```

Alternatively, if you will actually have more characters in front and behind (instead of just `d.` and `.f`), you could calculate the index of the first `.` and last `.` and then create a substring from that:

```
        private static KeyValuePair<string, string> Helper(KeyValuePair<string, string> x)
        {
            // d.b.f
            var startIndex = x.Key.IndexOf('.') + 1; // 2
            var endIndex = x.Key.LastIndexOf('.'); // 3
            var length = endIndex - startIndex; // 1
            var substring = x.Key.Substring(startIndex, length); // b
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(substring, x.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Depending on the constraints of the source key, some bounds checking would be necessary. Any key containing fewer than two `'.'`, for example `"d.f"`, would throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, however, the question doesn't give enough context to warrant putting time into writing all of that -- especially since they explicitly stated their `Dictionary`.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Its reasonable to assume that strings always have prefix & suffixes as d,f respectively. So min length of string is 2.
I see this is most optimal way even if we have to iterate over the keys few thousands of times.